# MySQL Group by conditioning

Tags: mysql, if-statement, group-by

Is there a way to only group by certain rows when a specific value is set?

i.e. I have the following table:

```
USERNO  |   FIRSTNAME   |   NAME    |   CUSTOMER    |   YEAR
1       |   Jon         |   Snow    |   0           |   2014
2       |   Williams    |   Spear   |   1           |   2015
1       |   John        |   Snow    |   1           |   2015
3       |   Sam         |   Wells   |   0           |   2014
3       |   Sam         |   Wells   |   0           |   2013
```

When `CUSTOMER` is 1, it should group by `USERNO`. So I want the following result:

```
USERNO  |   FIRSTNAME   |   NAME    |   CUSTOMER    |   YEAR
1       |   Jon         |   Snow    |   1           |   2014
2       |   Williams    |   Spear   |   1           |   2015
3       |   Sam         |   Wells   |   0           |   2014
3       |   Sam         |   Wells   |   0           |   2013
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what kind of values are you grouping? why `Jon Snow 0` disappeared from the result table? what is criteria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `UNION` for getting this type of results like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE CUSTOMER != 1
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE CUSTOMER = 1
GROUP BY USERNO;
```

OR You can also use `CASE` but you have to specify the `ELSE` part to group records when condition is not satisfied:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
GROUP BY CASE WHEN CUSTOMER  = 1 THEN USERNO ELSE columnname END;
```

OR You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` like this if you want your results to be grouped as a `COMMA` delimited list:

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CAST(USERNO) AS CHAR),
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CAST(FIRSTNAME) AS CHAR),
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CAST(NAME) AS CHAR),
  CUSTOMER,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CAST(YEAR) AS CHAR)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY CUSTOMER;
```

Comment: The query itself it pretty huge, so I'm afraid the `UNION` is not an option. I tried using a `CASE`, but nothing changed. I think it's because user 'Jon'  has `CUSTOMER` `0` and `1`.

Comment: You have to use `UNION` or you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` with `GROUP BY CUSTOMER`

Comment: I used the `CASE` method. I simply updated the code so `CUSTOMER` will always be the same for all users with the same `USERNO`. Thanks!

Comment: I had same issue,  `UNION` did the trick for me.  I needed all instances of records where `columnValue!=1` and then only summarized (grouped) instances of records where `columnValue=1`